# how to set the pivot in quick sort

Tags: c++, quicksort

I just update my codes it works but there some problems when I run it. I put some "cout" to debug my partiton part and I don't know whay it always set 0 to pivot.(the pivot should be last number that I inputed)
[image]

Here is my code

```
    int partiton(vector<int> &a, int low, int up)
{
      int pivot = a[up];
      int i = low-1;
      for (int j = low; j < up; j++)
      {
            if(a[j] <= pivot)
            {
                  i++;
                  swap(a[i], a[j]);
            }
      }
      swap(a[i+1], a[up]);
      cout<<"pivot: ";
      cout<<pivot<<" "<<endl;
      return i+1;
}

void quickSort(vector<int> &a, int low, int up)
{
      if(low < up)
      {
            int mid = partiton(a, low, up);
            //watch out! The mid position is on the palce, so we don't need to consider it again
            //That's why below is mid-1, not mid! Otherwise it will occur overflow error!
            quickSort(a, low, mid-1);
            quickSort(a, mid+1, up);
      }
}

void quickSort(vector<int>&, int, int);

int main()
{
    vector<int> A;

    int numbers;

    while(cin>>numbers)
    {
        A.push_back(numbers);
    }

    int low = 0;
    int up = A.size();

    cout<<"No sorted numbers: ";

    for(int i; i < up; i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    quickSort(A, low, up);

    cout<<"Has sorted numbers: ";

    for(int i; i < up; i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `quickSort_2.cpp:58:25:` means file `quickSort_2.cpp` row `58` column `25`. Then read the rest of it while looking at that line. Hint: `a` is a vector (just like you declared it, and like the error says).

Comment: How can you run something that doesn't compile?

Comment: How can you run a program with compilation errors?

Comment: A rule of thumb or common cause of `Segmentation Fault` errors is due to accessing memory outside of an array or dereferencing an invalid pointer.

Comment: You're passing a vector where an int array is expected. The error message is telling you exactly that.

Comment: plus you're reading the size of the vector before you push your int values to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to change `int a[]` into `vector<int> a` in definitions of both `partition` and `quickSort` functions. So `int partiton(vector<int> a, int low, int up)` and `void quickSort(vector<int> a, int low, int up)` should be sufficient for compilation-error-free code.

Compiler expects functions to be called with parameters which have the same types as in declarations of the functions, or at least the declared argument types have to be able to automatically be resolved (deduced or binded, in other words) to corresponding argument types of particular function calls. Compiler cannot bind `vector` to `int a[]` type, hence the error.